# The ResponseEntity returned by @ExceptionHandler in @ControllerAdvice can't be shown in swagger-ui.html

Tags: java, spring-boot, curl, error-handling, swagger-ui

The Response returned by @ExceptionHandler for MaxUploadSizeExceededException in @ControllerAdvice can't be shown in swagger-ui.html.

I am using Spring Boot for my RESTful Application. And using swagger-ui to use the RESTful APIs. One of my RESTful API is upload file, using Spring's MultipartFile.

The file size is limited, and when the uploaded file size exceeds the limit, there will be an exception as below thrown.
[Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.web.multipart.MaxUploadSizeExceededException: Maximum upload size exceeded...

To handle this exception to return an customized error message to client, I used the @ExceptionHandler in @ControllerAdvice to return the response. Below is my code.

```
    @ControllerAdvice
    public class GlobalControllerExceptionHandler{
        @ExceptionHandler(MaxUploadSizeExceededException.class)
        @ResponseBody
        public ResponseEntity<?> maxUploadSizeExceededException(MaxUploadSizeExceededException e) {        
            String bodyJson = "{\"ErrorMessage\":\"Maximum upload size exceeded.\"}";
            return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR).contentType(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN).body(bodyJson);
        }
    }
```

What I want to see in swagger-ui.html is like this:

```
    Response Body:
    {"ErrorMessage":"Maximum upload size exceeded."}

    Response Code:
    500
```

But now, I didn't see any content:

```
    Response Body:
    no content

    Response Code:
    0
```

One abnormal symptom I saw on Browser console is that, thet request header

Provisional headers shows "Provisional headers are shown":

```
!Provisional headers are shown
Accept: */*
Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=----WebKitFormBoundaryf7WjEeoDHtIm3ly1
Origin: http://localhost:8080
Referer: http://localhost:8080/SpringApp/swagger-ui.html
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/71.0.3578.98 Safari/537.36
X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest
```

I searched about "Provisional headers are shown", someone explains that, if such message shows, it means the request is actually not sent. But on my case, I actually got the requst on my Spring Application server side and I can even hit the @ErrorHandler method "maxUploadSizeExceededException".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have finally figured out the cause. The key symptom "!Provisional headers are shown" generally means request has failed to send. But actually I have hit the breakpoint on GlobalControllerExceptionHandler::maxUploadSizeExceededException. So the explain for "!Provisional headers are shown" in my case should be that, request has been sent, but data is not completely posted due to MaxUploadSizeExceededException (only partial data has been uploaded). On browser, if request post is not completed, the response will be swallowed. So swagger-ui can't display any response.
If using curl command to do the file upload, I can get the expected response in the output.

Answer (score 3):

Swagger does not parse your Java implementation.

If you want to add more information to the documentation you have to use Swagger annotations:

https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-core/wiki/Annotations-1.5.X

In your case something like:

```
@ApiResponses(value = { 
      @ApiResponse(code = 500, message = "Maximum upload size exceeded.")
})
```

But you have to add this annotation to your RestController. ControllerAdvice is not considered by swagger.

Comment: It doesn't work for my case. The symptom doesn't change after adding:`@ApiResponses(value = { @ApiResponse(code = 500, message = "xxx") })`

Comment: Oh now I see. This is in the control advice. Controller advice are no considered by swagger. you have to add the ApiResonse to the RestController method.

Comment: MaxUploadSizeExceededException can't be catched by RestController. I think this might because this exception is thrown out of RestController. So I have to use the ControllerAdvice.

Comment: Sure but the api doc must be on the controller